# Golang sending a response as w.Write vs Render.JSON in Chi Router?

Tags: json, http, go, response, chai

The documentation did not seem to help, and I could not find a lot of post that described the differences in go lang with `render.JSON` vs a `W.Write([]byte)`. We have a simple chi router that makes a post request and returns the data. I thought the only difference was auto setting content type, but when I use render.JSON it removes the keys.

Can anyone please tell me in a few human words if there is a difference and a good use case to use render vs write? Does anyone have any personal exp, or advice regarding this? I have read the documents, and seen response sent many different ways.

```
//Current Pref as I can define the headers, etc. 
    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json := []byte(body)
    w.Write(json)



//vs (sets content type, but removes the keys* and I am not sure why) 
render.JSON(w,r,interface)
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [code for render.JSON](https://github.com/go-chi/render/blob/3215478343fbc559bd3fc08f7031bb134d6bdad5/responder.go#L93-L107).  The function encodes the argument to JSON, sets a JSON content type header and writes the JSON to the response. The application can set response headers before calling render.JSON. The application can set the response status by calling [render.Status](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-chi/render#Status) before calling render.JSON.

The [ResponseWriter.Write](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Write) method writes bytes to the response as is.

Note a key difference between render.JSON and ResponseWriter.Write: The former function encodes the argument as JSON and the latter writes the bytes as is.

The render.JSON function encapsulates functionality commonly used by applications.  Use the function if you find it convenient.